# "localhost" vs "127.0.0.1" performance

Tags: python, windows, ip, xml-rpc

I've setup an XML-RPC server/client communication under Windows. What I've noticed is that if exchanged data volume become huge, there's a difference in starting the server listening on "localhost" vs. "127.0.0.1". If "127.0.0.1" is set, the communication speed is faster than using "localhost". Could somebody explain why? I thought it could be a matter on naming resolving, but....locally too?

Comment: What does your [`hosts` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) look like?

Comment: It's all commented with `#` character

Answer (score 12):

Every domain name gets resolved. There is no exception to this rule, including with regards to a local site.

When you make a request to `localhost`, localhost's IP gets resolved by the `host` file every time it gets requested. In Windows, the `host` file controls this. But if you make a request to `127.0.0.1`, the IP address is already resolved, so any request goes directly to this IP.

Comment: For me, it takes about one second to resolve (i.e., the difference between using localhost and 127.0.0.1). Is that normal? Could a virus scanner be in the way?

Comment: I've also experienced a similar behavior before on PHP server with apache .

Comment: @GijsvanOort I know I am 4 years late but you gotta check out your host file.